# Limit fields using JavaScript SDK Batch Request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-batch-request

Is it possible to limit the fields that are returned from Facebook's Batch request API using the JavaScript SDK?  For example:

```
    FB.api('/', 'POST', {
        batch: [
            { method: 'GET', relative_url: 'me'},
            ...
        ]
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

The first method of the batch request above returns the full user graph.  However, what if I only wanted to fetch a few fields (e.g. first_name and last_name).  Something like this would be nice, but doesn't work:

```
        batch: [
            { method: 'GET', relative_url: 'me', fields: 'first_name,last_name'},
            ...
        ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some requests you can use the `&fields=` appended to the end of the url.  like `/me?fields=first_name,last_name`

Answer (score 1):

Use [FQL queries](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) to filter out certian fields your require...
eg :

`SELECT uid, name, first_name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me()`

this query will return the user_id, full name, first name and 50x50 pixel profile picture for the user that is currently connected...